# Error:404 Cannot POST /api/tests for Postman and Express

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, postman

I am creating a MERN stack based website, and was able to write GET and POST requests for two out of the three models I have created so far: users and profile. The latest one, tests, is giving an error of Cannot POST /api/tests. Here's the code:

**server.js**

```
const connectDB = require('./config/db');
const app = express();
//Connecting DB
connectDB()

app.use(express.json({extended: false}));

app.get('/',(req,res)=>res.send('API Running'));

app.use('/api/users',require('./routes/api/users'));
app.use('/api/auth',require('./routes/api/auth'));
app.use('/api/profile',require('./routes/api/profile'));
app.use('/api/tests', require('./routes/api/tests'));

const PORT = process.env.Port || 5000;
app.listen(PORT, ()=> console.log(`Server started on port on ${PORT}`));
```

**Test.js**

```
const TestSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    domain: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    activeStatus: {
        type: Boolean,
        required: true
    },
    questions: [
        {
            question: {
                type: String,
                required: true
            },
            option1: {
                type: String,
                required: true
            },
            option2: {
                type: String,
                required: true
            },
            option3: {
                type: String,
                required: true
            },
            option4: {
                type: String,
                required: true
            },
            answer: {
                type: Number,
                required: false
            }
        }
    ]
});

module.exports = Test = mongoose.model('test', TestSchema);
```

**tests.js**

```
const router = express.Router();
const { check, validateResult } = require('express-validator/check');
const auth = require('../../middleware/Auth');

const Test = require('../../models/Test');
const User = require('../../models/User');

// @route  POST api/tests
// @desc   Create or Update a test
// @access Private
router.post('/',  [
    check('name', 'Name is required').not().isEmpty(),
    check('domain', 'Domain is required').not().isEmpty(),
    check('status', 'Status is required').not().isEmpty()
    
], 
async (req, res) => {
    console.log("entered");
    const errors = validationResult(req);
    if(!errors.isEmpty()) {
        return res.status(400).json({ errors: errors.array() });
    }

    const {
        name,
        domain,
        status
    } = req.body;

    //build test object
    const testFields = {};
    if(name) testFields.name = name;
    if(domain) {console.log(123); testFields.domain = domain;}
    if(status) testFields.status = status;
    testFields.questions = {};

    try {
        //see if test exists
        // let test = await Test.findOne({name});
        // if(test){
        //     return res.status(400).json({ errors: [{msg: "Test already exists"}] });
        // }

        //create
        test = new Test(testFields);
        await test.save();
        res.json(test);

        console.log(testFields);

        res.send('Test Created')
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err.message);
        res.status(500).send('Server Error');
    }
    
});

// @route  GET api/tests
// @desc   Get particular test
// @access Private
router.get('/', auth, async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const test = await Profile.findById(req.test.id);
        console.log(test);
        if(!test)
            return res.status(400).json({ msg: 'Test not found' });
        res.json(test);
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err.message);
        res.status(500).send('Server Error');
    }
});

module.exports = router;
```

Things I've already tried:

- Checked and rechecked the URL entered in Postman (http://localhost:5000/api/tests)
- Set the URL type in Postman to POST
- Made sure the URL was properly registered, and compared with working URLs and files

Even after this, nothing has worked so far. I am fairly new to this, so that might be the cause of my oversight, please do let me know if you can spot where it's going wrong.

Comment: Can you show us the postman request url

Comment: This has to be a frontend problem since express would give a 500 status if it wasn't

Comment: You have a `res.send()` after the `res.json()` in your POST route. Maybe that contributes to the problem. Also a snapshot of the error would be helpfull.